# Console.log not working inside of setInterval for Tampermonkey

Tags: javascript, setinterval, tampermonkey

I've used `setInterval()` plenty of times in typical scripts, but not with userscripts. For some reason, `console.log()` isn't working, but only inside of the setInterval. The alert, however, *is* working. Any ideas..? Should I not be using console.log?

To clarify, the first `console.log("Started!");` does in fact print started.

```
(function() {
    console.log("Started!");
    setInterval(function(){ findAndReplace();}, 3000);
})();

function findAndReplace() {
    alert("hi");
    console.log("Hey");
}
```

Comment: Hmm.. seems to work here: http://jsfiddle.net/seyenaz/ss20m0qt/

Comment: It works in IE, but not FireFox.

Comment: @OmriAharon The problem is that it works in something like JSFiddle, but NOT in a tampermonkey script, where it's injected into the existing, loaded webpage.

Comment: This works perfectly fine in Tampermonkey.  Something you are not showing us is the problem. **Complete** (but concise to the problem) script? This includes the metadata block.  Chrome and TM versions?  Non-standard TM settings?

Comment: Also be aware that some few web sites do trash the console functions; I've seen this on about 3 sites, IIRC. The `console.log("Started!")` would be firing (just) before that happens, *if* that is your case.

Comment: To check if what @BrockAdams pointed out is the case, try sticking your initial `console.log` in a timeout and see if it still works.

Comment: @BrockAdams this was correct, Twitter overrides this. I ended up just putting `console.log = console.__proto__.log` at the start of my functions and it works just fine now.

Answer (score 15, accepted):

The answer supplied by OPer didn't work for me, it seems that's no longer an option. Grant GM_log to your script and use the GM_log function as a substitute for console.log.

Add this to the script header...
`// @grant GM_log`

Use this in your code...
`GM_log('<my debug message>');`

Answer (score 1):

Apparently, Twitter overrides console.log. The "solution" is to put `console.log = console.__proto__.log` at the top of my functions.

Comment: Youtube now does something similar, but this solution doesn't appear to work for that site, at least on firefox.

Answer (score 0):

To your tamermonkey script header add

`// @grant       GM_log`

then `console.log("hello world");` should work